# rake aborted! undefined method `sorcery' || rvm rails db:seed error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

```
rake aborted! undefined method `sorcery' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x93a9554>
```

really don't know what is wrong here. I installed https://github.com/NoamB/sorcery as per the instructions.

Then I decided it wasn't exactly what I wanted. Done a lot of faffing about but eventually just decided to revert to an earlier pre sorcery commit.

Trouble is now I get the above message every time I try to seed or migrate a db.

I have tried emptying the rvm gemset, uninstalling the sorcery gem, have looked in the seeds.rb and schema.rb as well as the Gemfile and I am definitely using the pre 'sorcery' version of my app.

I even tried dropping the db. rake db:create worked but back to the same error with rake db:seed.

It's my first time using rails so not entirely sure what's going on and 'undefined method' returns so many hits I can't find a clear debug path.

trace

/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing'
/home/kzu/Development/hub-blog/config/initializers/sorcery.rb:5:in`'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in `load'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`block in load'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:245:in`load'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:588:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in`each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/engine.rb:587:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in`method_missing'
/home/kzu/Development/hub-blog/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in`require'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:297:in`block (2 levels) in initialize_tasks'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `call'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`block in execute'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`execute'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in`invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in`each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:203:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:183:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in`invoke'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/railties/databases.rake:346:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in`call'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:246:in `block in execute'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in`each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `execute'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:184:in`block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:177:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/task.rb:170:in`invoke'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:143:in `invoke_task'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`block (2 levels) in top_level'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in `each'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:101:in`block in top_level'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:110:in `run_with_threads'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:95:in`top_level'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:73:in `block in run'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in`standard_exception_handling'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@global/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval'
/home/kzu/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `'
Tasks: TOP => db:abort_if_pending_migrations => environment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that you still have a sorcery.rb file in your app folder, in config/initializer can you please check that ?

Comment: Man thanks for stopping by. I did indeed have that file left over. I think because I never committed it, it wouldn't have been touched by the git branch change- is that the way things work?

Comment: If you don't commit files and do a git stash that will only remove the modification in your committed files. Any created folder or files will be left, to remove uncommitted files you have to do git clean -f -d that will remove any uncommitted files and directory (-f for files, -d for directories)